# Silverlight cannot update property after animation runs

Tags: silverlight, xaml, animation

Im trying to create a simple pan and zoom app using silverlight 4, but Im having trouble updating the TranslateTransform and ScaleTransform properties **after** I run an animation on them.

I have tried to set the FillBehaviour to Stop, with no success.

Here is the code that I have:

```
<Canvas x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="800" Height="600">
        <Canvas x:Name="PanningCanvas" Height="600" Width="800">
            <Canvas.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="CanvasScale"/>
                    <SkewTransform/>
                    <RotateTransform/>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="CanvasTransform"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <Rectangle x:Name="MovingRect" Fill="#FF834040" Height="209" Canvas.Left="219" Stroke="#FF500505" Canvas.Top="220" Width="329" StrokeThickness="2"/>
        </Canvas>
        <Button Content="Animate" Width="107" Canvas.Left="38" Canvas.Top="46" ClickMode="Press" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Canvas>
```

And here is the C# behind it all (slightly abbreviated)

```
public partial class MainPage : UserControl
    {
        private ManipulationProcessor2D manipulationProcessor;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.manipulationProcessor = new ManipulationProcessor2D(Manipulations2D.Translate | Manipulations2D.Scale);

            this.manipulationProcessor.Delta += OnManipulationDelta;

            Touch.FrameReported += OnCapturedTouchReported;
        }

        private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, Manipulation2DDeltaEventArgs e)
        {
            float zoomVal = e.Delta.ScaleX;
            Point pinchPoint = new Point(e.OriginX, e.OriginY);

            float xTranslation = e.Delta.TranslationX;
            float yTranslation = e.Delta.TranslationY;

            if (zoomVal != 1.0)
            {
                Zoom(zoomVal, PanningCanvas.RenderTransform.Inverse.Transform(pinchPoint), pinchPoint, xTranslation, yTranslation, true);
            }
            else if (xTranslation != 0 || yTranslation != 0)
            {
                Translate(xTranslation, yTranslation);
            }
        }

        public void Zoom(double zoom, Point pinchPosition, Point physicalPosition, float xTranslation, float yTranslation, bool isFinger)
        {
            if (isFinger)
            {
                CanvasScale.ScaleX = CanvasScale.ScaleX * zoom;
                CanvasScale.ScaleY = CanvasScale.ScaleY * zoom;

                CanvasTransform.X = -1 * (pinchPosition.X * CanvasScale.ScaleX - physicalPosition.X);
                CanvasTransform.Y = -1 * (pinchPosition.Y * CanvasScale.ScaleY - physicalPosition.Y);
            }
            else
            {
                CanvasScale.ScaleX = CanvasScale.ScaleX + zoom;
                CanvasScale.ScaleY = CanvasScale.ScaleY + zoom;
            }
        }

        private void Translate(float xTranslation, float yTranslation)
        {
            CanvasTransform.X += xTranslation;
            CanvasTransform.Y += yTranslation;
        }

        private void OnCapturedTouchReported(object sender, TouchFrameEventArgs e)
        {
            //..removed..//

            // process manipulations
            this.manipulationProcessor.ProcessManipulators(DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks,manipulators);
        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            AnimatePosition(new Point(400, 300), 1);
            AnimateScale(1.2, 1);
        }

        private Storyboard translateStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        private Storyboard scaleStoryboard = new Storyboard();

        public void AnimatePosition(Point destinationPoint, double lengthOfAnimation)
        {
            Point offset = new Point(destinationPoint.X, destinationPoint.Y);

            var translationAnimationX = new DoubleAnimation() { SpeedRatio = 1, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(lengthOfAnimation)), To = offset.X };
            translateStoryboard.Children.Add(translationAnimationX);

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translationAnimationX, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.X)"));

            var translationAnimationY = new DoubleAnimation() { SpeedRatio = 1, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(lengthOfAnimation)), To = offset.Y };
            translateStoryboard.Children.Add(translationAnimationY);

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translationAnimationY, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[3].(TranslateTransform.Y)"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(translateStoryboard, PanningCanvas);

            translateStoryboard.Begin();
        }

        public void AnimateScale( double scale, double lengthOfAnimation)
        {
            var scaleAnimationX = new DoubleAnimation() { SpeedRatio = 1, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(lengthOfAnimation)), To = scale };
            scaleStoryboard.Children.Add(scaleAnimationX);

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimationX, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleX)"));

            var scaleAnimationY = new DoubleAnimation() { SpeedRatio = 1, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(lengthOfAnimation)), To = scale };
            scaleStoryboard.Children.Add(scaleAnimationY);

            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(scaleAnimationY, new PropertyPath("(UIElement.RenderTransform).(TransformGroup.Children)[0].(ScaleTransform.ScaleY)"));
            Storyboard.SetTarget(scaleStoryboard, PanningCanvas);

            scaleStoryboard.Begin();
        }
    }
```

The issue is that after I click the button, I cannot translate or zoom anymore...

please help!

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I got it working, but I dont know why.

Changing the animation to work like this:

```
        Storyboard translateStoryboard = new Storyboard();
        Point offset = new Point(destinationPoint.X, destinationPoint.Y);

        var translationAnimationX = new DoubleAnimation() { SpeedRatio = 1, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(lengthOfAnimation)), To = offset.X };
        var translationAnimationY = new DoubleAnimation() { SpeedRatio = 1, Duration = new Duration(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(lengthOfAnimation)), To = offset.Y };

        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translationAnimationX, new PropertyPath("X"));
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(translationAnimationY, new PropertyPath("Y"));

        Storyboard.SetTargetName(translationAnimationX, "CanvasTransform");
        Storyboard.SetTargetName(translationAnimationY, "CanvasTransform");

        translateStoryboard.Children.Add(translationAnimationX);
        translateStoryboard.Children.Add(translationAnimationY);

        translateStoryboard.Begin();
```

Did the trick, but I dont know why...

Can someone please explain it to me?